# Max(varchar2) expression result and behaviour in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

If I use `max()` on `varchar2` field, what it will return in oracle ?

Ex:

```
SELECT max(name) 
FROM users;
```

Comment: It orders the values based on the collation -- which in basically all cases in alphabetically.

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Answer (score 0):

It would select the highest value alphanumerically.

more information here
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch5lingsort.htm

Answer (score 0):

It will return result of following query.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
   SELECT name FROM users
   WHERE name IS NOT NULL
   ORDER BY name DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

This result depends on your [NLS_SORT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams130.htm#REFRN10127) settings. In my database it returns a name which starts with "ş".

Answer (score 0):

Oracle will use lexicographic order. see this SQL fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/585a7/1

Answer (score 0):

It will return the value of name that would appear on the last row of:

```
select name
from users
where name is not null
order by name;
```

or if there are no non-null name values it will return null.